Flagging as off-topic limited to meta
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8887/the-compilation-of-miracl-for-the-dsp-c6713-of-texas-instruments seems off-topic for crypto.se, but the only option available under Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > Migration is meta.crypto.stackexchange.com.
It seems like this particular question is better suited to SO - am I missing something here?

Some general policy about how to close-vote:
If you think that a question is off-topic, please vote it simply as "off-topic" (with one of the reasons provided, or a custom reason). If enough people (or a moderator) think the same, the question will be put on hold as "off-topic", and no more answers allowed until it is improved and reopened.
This should be done independently of whether or not you want to migrate the question.

This close dialog is only available for users with the "Close question" privilege, which needs 500 reputation on public beta sites like our one.
We might need some more canned reasons here – moderators are able to add some or deactivate the existing ones. I hope some high-rep users will start to use the "other" option and fill in reasons, so we can get some sample of what is needed. In your example the text could be something like this:
This question appears to be off-topic because it is about
software development, not about cryptographic algorithms or protocols.

For users with less reputation (but at least 15), there is a similar flag dialog (under "This question doesn't belong here"), but it doesn't contain the "Other" variant, so you can't add your own reason. (You can use the free-form flag mentioned in the next paragraph instead.)
If you also think that it is a good fit on another Stack Exchange site (not merely better there than here), please do use the "flag for moderator attention" option in addition, and type in the free-text field where you think it should be migrated to, and maybe also a sentence why it fits there. One of the moderators will have a look and decide if it is worth migrating.
In general, we should not migrate questions which are on-topic here (even if they might be slightly better on the other site), nor do we migrate off-topic questions which, while on-topic on the other side, are actually bad questions – these should be simply closed as off-topic, and the asker might get a hint how to ask a better new question on the other site.
Please note that the close-reason dialog changed recently, there is a blog post about this.

What I'm seeing is there's no way to flag a question as generally off-topic. You have to select one of the local reasons (mathematics, analyzing or decyphering a block of data , reference recommendations), or belongs on another site to enable the Flag Question button. None of the local reasons were appropriate in this case, and the only option to suggest moving to another site is meta, so I don't understand how I can vote it as "off-topic".

Hmm, I also see an "other" option there. Maybe this is only available for users with a minimum reputation? Before the recent changes there surely was such an option, I'll have to check again.

@archie Obviously I did never see the "flag question as doesn't belong here" dialog in the last almost two years, since I (as a moderator here and high-rep user on Stack Overflow) normally have the close-voting dialog, not the close-flagging one, which looks slightly different, even more so since the latest change. I edited my post to be more clear about this.

@PaŭloEbermann: For those of us with lower rep, we can leave a 'generic' flag (with explanation), but to give the 'correct' flag we follow the menu options "I am flagging this question because" -> "it should be closed for another reason..." -> "off-topic because..." -> "belongs on another site in the network" ->  at which point it would really help to have security and stack overflow offered rather than just meta!

Please flag questions, that need to be migrated to another site in the network.
On Security.SE, it took about a year after the site left beta until other options for migration were made available. Those options were picked based on statistical information of migrations (mods are able to migrate). Those statistical information are not just the total number of migrations per target-site, but also include the percentage of migrated posting that were not well received.
I guess, we will have to wait some more, until voting to migrate will become available on Crypto.

I'm assuming you mean flag for moderator attention (the off-topic being the type of flagging I was attempting). I'm assuming this boils down to "close voting isn't functional yet, just flag to a moderator for now".

Yes. Well, close voting in general does work, just migrations need moderators.
